# unicode recognization is it utf-8 utf-16 or any thing else?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

i m using postgre database it has encoding UTF-8 
in that unicode for marathi word pimpri is like this 
\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 \u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947

and when at client side i wrote a code 
String tempString=Strings.toEscapedUnicode(strQueryString[1]);
it generate unicode like this 
u00E0\u00A4\u00AA\u00E0\u00A4\u00BF\u00E0\u00A4\u00AA\u00E0\u00A4\u0082\u00E0\u00A4\u00B0\u00E0\u00A5\u0080

so i have problem for matching it.

i have problem that how to recognize in which formate is?
u00E0\u00A4\u00AA\u00E0\u00A4\u00BF\u00E0\u00A4\u00AA\u00E0\u00A4\u0082\u00E0\u00A4\u00B0\u00E0\u00A5\u0080 is this in utf8 or utf16 or utf32

and also how to convert utf8 to utf16 using java is there any method for that???

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have to handle with the encoding? The PostgreSQL JDBC driver should handle it, Java uses UTF-16 internally. So you can simply compare the string got by `ResultSet.getString()` with any other string or pass any string as parameter if using `PreparedStatement.setString()`.

Answer (score 1):

The data in your database appears to be UTF-16.

But your client code appears to be UTF-8.  Looking at your data, the first character ([DEVANAGARI LETTER PA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/092a/index.htm)) which is `\u092A` in UTF-16 and `0xE0 0xA4 0xAA` in UTF-8.

In Java, you can convert your string to the byte sequence for a specific encoding using one of the [getBytes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) overload.